# Create new database connections in Quarkus during runtime

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, quarkus

I have a java REST API application using Quarkus as the framework. The application uses a PostgreSQL database, which is configured via the *application.properties* config file for hibernate entities (using "quarkus-hibernate-orm" module) etc. However, there are cases where i will have to dynamically connect to a remote database (connection info will be supplied by parameters) to read and write data from during runtime as well. How do i go about this the best way with Quarkus? For simplicity reasons we can assume that the remote databases are of the same type (PostgreSQL) so we don't have to worry about whether the correct driver is locally available or not.

Is there something provided by Quarkus or the environment to establish these connections and read/write? i dont need an ORM layer here necessarily, as i may not know the structure beforehand either. Simple queries are also sufficient. When i try to research this subject i can only get information about static hibernate or datasource configurations in Quarkus, but i won't know what they look like beforehand. Basically, is there some kind of "db connection provider" etc. i should use or do i simply have to manually create new plain JDBC connections in my own code for it?

Comment: You just need a connection, right? No injectable bean? If so, this has nothing to do with quarkus and is outlined in the [JDBC Documentation of postgres (`jdbc.postgres.org`)](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/use/).

Comment: @Turing85 I suppose you are right, i was just wondering if i was missing something obvious here. It felt so "hacky" to just make a raw JDBC connection, but at the end of the day not everything needs to be abstracted away behind complex frameworks.

Comment: I guess i need to find out where the driver class is sitting hibernate is using, but maybe that is something about hibernate API rather than Quarkus as well.

Comment: I am confused. You said you wanted a `Connection`, and by using the postgres driver directly, we can create a `Connection`. What exactly do you mean by the "*driver class [...] hibernate is using*"? The driver class is loaded explicitly. In our `pom.xml`, we should see a dependency to `quarkus-jdbc-postgresql`.